# When an -i form (連用形{れんようけい}) of a verb seems to be a suffix rather than a prefix?

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntax, renyōkei

[In a previous question about コーヒー割り](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15150/why-is-coffee-with-shochu-or-awamori-called-%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%92%E3%83%BC%E5%89%B2%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A-split-divided-coffee) I learned that 割り is a form of the verb 割{わ}る "to dilute".

Now I'm trying to understand the grammatical process by which this 割り form of 割る can be added to nouns such as 水 and コーヒー.

I've learned that 割り is the -i form, conjunctive, continuative, or 連用形{れんようけい} form of the verb. In fact it turns out that I keep asking questions about this form from different angles, not realizing it's the same thing each time!

Now when [I look up Wikipedia to learn more about this form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#i_form) and how it is being used in コーヒー割り I actually find that -i forms are usually used as prefixes.

So this must be an "unusual" case since it appears to be being used like a suffix. What is this particular use of the -i form? How can I understand and use constructions of this type generally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-i form of a verb, among other things, can be used to form nouns that are derived from this verb. For example

to discount (v) -> discount (n): 割り{わり}引く{びく} -> 割引{わりびき}

to rest/to have take a day off (v) -> rest/holiday (n): 休{やす}む -> 休{やす}み

to apply (v) -> application (n): 申{もう}し込{こ}む -> 申{もう}し込{こ}み

So I believe this is not the case of a verb form being a suffix but rather of a noun formed from a verb.

This is also similar in case of words from your previous question. For example, my dictionary shows the following example for 水割り, which suggests it being a noun:

水割りをもう一杯ください。

Comment: Ah so it's somewhat like an English gerund / present participle or infinitive?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can make a direct comparison to English in this case. Note that sometimes in English the form of verb and noun is the same, e.g. cited above discount, sometimes changes.

Comment: Yes that's why I said "somewhat". You can almost never make direct comparisons between any features of any two languages really.

Comment: @hippietrail Most any 連用形 of a verb can be used like a noun.  But 連用形 of adjectives are different and can't be used like nouns, with a few exceptions.  (Some linguists suggest that the two don't form a coherent category, but many follow traditional grammar in treating them as the same thing because of their other similarities.)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a thought that is too long for a comment but based on the following 水割り seems to be the natural order:

> To dilute with water = 水で割る　ー＞ 水割り
>
> To take a 1/10th, or 10% = 一割 (same order); 15%= 一割５分　(seems logical)

If we look at other words containing 割り　then the order they come is consistent with what you would expect in long form, eg:

> Ratio: 割合 would be consistent with 割り合う
>
> (I have never seen this verb used but 合う will normally be the second verb in a construction such as 話し合う）
>
> Allotment: 割り当て would be consistent with 割り当てる
>
> (which does exist)